# Let $f: A \to B$ be a function. Then $\forall C\subseteq A, f^{-1}(f(C))=C$ if and only if $f$ is an injection.

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

Claim: Let $f: A \to B$ be a function. Then $\forall C\subseteq A, f^{-1}(f(C))=C$ if and only if $f$ is an injection.

Proof. ($\Rightarrow$) Assume $f$ is not an injection. Then $\exists x,y \in A$ such that $f(x)=f(y)$ and $x \ne y$. We need only to find some subset $C$ of $A$ such that $f^{-1}(f(C)) \ne C$.

Let $C=\{x\} \subseteq A$. Because $x \ne y, y \notin C$.

Note that $f^{-1}(f(C))=\{a \in A|f(a) \in f(C)\}$.
And that $f(C)=\{b \in B|b=f(x)\}=\{f(x)\}=\{f(y)\}$, so $y \in f^{-1}(f(C))$. Since two sets are equal if and only if they have the same elements, it follows that $f^{-1}(f(C)) \ne C$.
Thus if $f^{-1}(f(C))=C$, then $f$ is an injection.

($\Leftarrow$) Suppose $f$ is an injection. Then $\forall x,y \in A, f(x)=f(y) \Rightarrow x=y$.

- ($\subseteq$) Let $x \in f^{-1}(f(C))$. Then $x \in \{a \in A |\exists b \in f(C)$ s.t. $f(a)=b\}$. Thus $f(x)=b$ for some $b \in f(C)=\{d \in B | \exists y \in C$ s.t. $d=f(y)\}$. And since $b \in f(C)$, then $b=f(y)$ for some $y \in C$. As $b=f(x)$ and $b=f(y)$, then $f(x)=f(y)$. Now $f$ is an injection, so $f(x)=f(y) \Rightarrow x=y$. This means that $x \in C$, and hence $f^{-1}(f(C)) \subseteq C$.
- ($\supseteq$) Let $x \in C$. Then $f(x) \in f(C)$, and thus $x \in f^{-1}(f(C))$. Thus $C \subseteq f^{-1}(f(C))$.

As $f^{-1}(f(C)) \subseteq C$ and $C \subseteq f^{-1}(f(C))$, then $f^{-1}(f(C))=C$.

Therefore, $f^{-1}(f(C))=C$ if and only if $f$ is an injection.

Is this correct?

Comment: And the question is?

Comment: Perhaps make the solution verification part clear!

Comment: Looks good to me!

Comment: @ArturoMagidin excuse me - I got confused with one of the things they said. It’s fine for infinite sets too - I started thinking about cardinals for no reason at all

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Done

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The proofs seem correct, but really too verbose.

($\Rightarrow$) Suppose $f(x)=f(y)$ and set $C=\{x\}$. Then, by assumption, $y\in f^{-1}(f(C))=C$, so $y=x$.

($\Leftarrow$) Suppose $f$ is injective and take $C\subseteq A$. It is easy to see that $C\subseteq f^{-1}(f(C))$. Now suppose $f$ is injective and consider $x\in f^{-1}(f(C))$. Then $f(x)\in f(C)$, by definition and therefore there exists $y\in C$ such that $f(x)=f(y)$. Since $f$ is injective, $y=x$, so $x\in C$.